# jest.mock is not a function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, enzyme

Could you please tell me how to test `componentDidMount` function using `enzyme`.I am fetching data from the server in `componentDidMount` which work perfectly.Now I want to test this function.

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/oq7kwzrnj5

```
  componentDidMount(){
        axios
          .get('https://*******/getlist')
          .then(res => {
            this.setState({
              items : res.data.data
            })
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err))
      }
```

I try like this

```
 it("check ajax call", () => {
      const componentDidMountSpy = jest.spyOn(List.prototype, 'componentDidMount');

      const wrapper = shallow(<List />);
    });
```

see updated code

https://codesandbox.io/s/oq7kwzrnj5

```
it("check ajax call", () => {
      jest.mock('axios', () => {
        const exampleArticles:any = {
          data :{
            data:['A','B','c']
          }
        }
        return {
          get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(exampleArticles)),
        };
      });


    expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

error
[image]

Comment: To test that react will call componentDidMount is testing library internals. No point to do that. I think you want to test that axios was executed.

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk yes how i will do that

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk could you please help me out how i will test axis.get method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You look like you're almost there. Just add the `expect()`:

```
expect(componentDidMountSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

If you need to check if it was called multiple times, you can use `toHaveBeenCalledTimes(count)`.

Also, be sure to [`mockRestore()`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockrestore) the mock at the end to make it unmocked for other tests.

```
List.prototype.componentDidMount.restore();
```

---

To mock `axios` (or any `node_modules` package), create a folder named `__mocks__` in the same directory as `node_modules`, like:

```
 --- project root
  |-- node_modules
  |-- __mocks__
```

Inside of there, make a file named `<package_name>.js` (so `axios.js`).

Inside of there, you'll create your mocked version.

If you just need to mock `.get()`, it can be as simple as:

```
export default { get: jest.fn() }
```

Then in your code, near the top (after `import`s), add:

```
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios');
```

In your test, add a call to `axios.get.mockImplementation()` to specify what it'll return:

```
axios.get.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ data: { data: [1, 2, 3] } });
```

This will then make `axios.get()` return whatever you gave it (in this case, a `Promise` that resolves to that object).

You can then do whatever tests you need to do.

Finally, end the test with:

```
axios.get.mockReset();
```

to reset it to it's default *mocked* implementation.

Comment: @how to test `axios.get` function

Comment: how to mock my service you didn't get my Question

Comment: I've updated your answer. You might want to tweak your title and clarify a bit in your question that you want to test what is inside the function, not that it is called.

Comment: You didn't include `jest.mock('axios')` after the imports in your `.spec` file. Adding that fixed it.

Comment: Check your error messages. It says "require.resolve" isn't a function. That's an issue with that sandbox. The code itself should work.